# How to handle the maximun export limit size file for drive api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download some google doc files but after it i need to use the export method to convert into the microsoft word mimetype, it works fine until it found a file with more than 10 mb size, the api documentation said this is the limit size to export a document but i really need to download those files, everything in my script works fine except this the error that is throwing is

"This file is too large to be exported.". Details: "This file is too large to be exported."
so , is there anyway to avoid this limitation or to export the document inside the folder that is content

**EDIT:** the document that i am trying to download is not public so i think i need to auth the request to get the content

**EDIT 2** : script:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


  
def main():
    
   
    #----------------------Google drive auth-----------------------------
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets()
    
   
    
    # ID of folder that contain the wanted files
    query = "'[ID OF THE FOLDER]' in parents"

    response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                spaces='drive',
                                fields='files(id, name, parents, webViewLink,exportLinks)').execute()
    
    baseURL="https://docs.google.com/document/d/"
    for document in response['files']:
        
        
        
        downloadURL=baseURL+document["id"]+"/export?format=doc"
        

            
        r = requests.get(downloadURL)  
        
        with open('pathtosabe, 'wb') as f:

            f.write(r.content)
            
   
  
        

            
        
main()
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide your current script? And, in your situation, which is your Google Document publicly shared or not shared?

Comment: well i noticed my problem is that the doc that i am trying to download is just visible for whom the document is shared so as the request isnt auth it just can get the file name but not it content, i still don´t know how to solve it. so my question could change to "how to auth my request with the credentials of gdrive api"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, your Google Document is not publicly shared and you cannot retrieve the contents of Google Document using Drive API. Is my understanding correct? And about your new question of `how to auth my request with the credentials of gdrive api`, I think that [the sample script of the Quickstart for python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) might be useful.

Comment: is just that the problem is with the 10 mb size limit of the file to be exported, the api did not let to download a file bigger than 10 mb and all my files are bigget than that, that´s why i am trying to use requests instead of the api, but i thinks there is a way to use the same credentials to auth the requests just that i can´t understand https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the script for replicating your issue?

Comment: just added it  .

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the script. From your comments, I understand that your Google Document is not publicly shared. Under this situation, when I saw your script, it seems that your `r = requests.get(downloadURL)` doesn't use the access token. I think that in this case, the HTML of login screen is returned and the error of `This file is too large to be exported.` doesn't occur. How about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229130/discussion-between-user14398375-and-tanaike).

Comment: well, that is the problem i don´t know how to use the acces token in the request the file is downloaded but the content is shown as corrupted i tryed with a public document and the content was visible

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your following [replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339632/how-to-handle-the-maximun-export-limit-size-file-for-drive-api/66344211#comment117290716_66339632),

> well, that is the problem i don´t know how to use the acces token in the request the file is downloaded but the content is shown as corrupted i tryed with a public document and the content was visible

I thought that when your Google Document is not publicly shared, when the access token is used for your script of `r = requests.get(downloadURL)`, it might work. So in this answer, I would like to propose the modified script using the access token retrieved from the authorization script of your script.

#### Modified script:

```
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

# Call the Drive v3 API
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets()

# ID of folder that contain the wanted files
query = "'[ID OF THE FOLDER]' in parents"
response = service.files().list(q=query,
                            spaces='drive',
                            fields='files(id, name, parents, webViewLink,exportLinks)').execute()

access_token = creds.token # Added
baseURL="https://docs.google.com/document/d/"
for document in response['files']:
    downloadURL=baseURL+document["id"]+"/export?format=doc"
    r = requests.get(downloadURL, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})  # Modified
    with open('pathtosabe', 'wb') as f:  # Modified
        f.write(r.content)
```

- In your script, `'pathtosabe,` of `with open('pathtosabe, 'wb') as f:` is not enclosed by the single quote. Please be careful this. If you want to use `pathtosabe` as a variable, please declare it and modify to `with open(pathtosabe, 'wb') as f:`.

Comment: i really thanks you a lot, srry for the delay replying i just fall asleep