# how to auth a request to download google drive files

Tags: python-requests

i want to download files from google drive, in especific i want to download some google docs, the problem is that i can´t use the api because the api has a limit of 10 mb to export google docs, so i was trying to use requests module, the problem is that the request isn´t auth so the content of the download is not visible because the google doc is not publicy shared, is there any way to auth my request to download the needed files?
i used

```
r=requests.get(url)
```

and then

```
with open(path,wb) as f:
   f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url

Comment: Is my answer for [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66339632) useful?

Comment: thanks you a lot @Tanaike it was really usefull

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.